On average, how long does it take for a Random Walk to go somewhere for the first time?
Earlier I posted a question about deriving properties of a Random Walk (Deriving Properties of the Random Walk). Now, I am interested in learning how to derive properties for the First Hitting Time of a Random Walk.
Suppose I have a general random walk (discrete time). Let $X_n$ be the position of the random walk after n steps, starting at $X_0 = 0$. For each step:
$$
X_n = X_{n-1} + Y_n
$$
Where $Y_n$ is the step taken at time n, defined as:
$$
Y_n = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{with probability } p \\
-1 & \text{with probability } 1-p
\end{cases}
$$

1) Mean Value: Using logic, we can set up some basic definitions:
$$ \text{Let } T_n \text{ be the first hitting time of position } n. $$
$$ \text{Let } E[T_n] \text{ be the expected value of } T_n. $$
From here we can write a recurrence relation:
$$ E[T_n] = \frac{1}{2}(1 + E[T_{n-1}]) + \frac{1}{2}(1 + E[T_{n+1}]) $$
This equation states that from position $n$, we have a 50% chance of moving to $n-1$, and a 50% chance of moving to $n+1$. In both cases, we add 1 to account for the step we just took.
Rearranging the terms:
$$ E[T_n] = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n-1}] + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n+1}] $$
This is a second-order linear difference equation. To solve it, we need two boundary conditions:

$E[T_0] = 0$ : we're already at 0, so it takes 0 steps to reach it
$ E[T_1] = 1$  : from 0, it takes on average 1 step to reach 1

Based on some Youtube videos I watched, recurrence relations require assuming a general solution of a specific form and then solving:
$$ E[T_n] = an^2 + bn + c $$
Where $a, b, and c$ are constants we need to determine.
Substituting this into our recurrence relation:
$$ an^2 + bn + c = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(a(n-1)^2 + b(n-1) + c) + \frac{1}{2}(a(n+1)^2 + b(n+1) + c) $$
Expanding:
$$ an^2 + bn + c = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(an^2 - 2an + a + bn - b + c) + \frac{1}{2}(an^2 + 2an + a + bn + b + c) $$
Simplifying:
$$ an^2 + bn + c = 1 + an^2 + bn + c + a $$
Looking at the above, this can only be true if: $ a = 1 , b = 0  c = -1 $
Therefore, our general solution is: $ E[T_n] = n^2 - 1 $
Unfortunately, this does not satisfy the boundary conditions - but its close:
$$E[T_0] = 0^2 - 1 = -1$$
$$E[T_1] = 1^2 - 1 = 0$$
I am hoping that for large values of $n$, the extra $1$ is negligible?

2) Variance
Denote the variance as $\text{Var}(T_n)$ and $T_n$ is the first hitting time of position $n$ (from the previous part). In general (i.e. from first principles), we know that the variance of a random variable is a function of its expectations:
$$ \text{Var}(T_n) = E[T_n^2] - (E[T_n])^2 $$
Here I am going to assume that $E[T_n] \approx n^2$. Thus, we need to find $E[T_n^2]$.
Setting up a similar recurrence relation for $E[T_n^2]$:
$$ E[T_n^2] = \frac{1}{2}(1 + T_{n-1})^2 + \frac{1}{2}(1 + T_{n+1})^2 $$
Expanding:
$$ E[T_n^2] = \frac{1}{2}(1 + 2T_{n-1} + T_{n-1}^2) + \frac{1}{2}(1 + 2T_{n+1} + T_{n+1}^2) $$
$$ E[T_n^2] = 1 + E[T_{n-1}] + E[T_{n+1}] + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n-1}^2] + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n+1}^2] $$
We know that $E[T_{n-1}] + E[T_{n+1}] = 2E[T_n] - 2$ from our previous analysis. Substituting this:
$$ E[T_n^2] = 1 + 2E[T_n] - 2 + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n-1}^2] + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n+1}^2] $$
Rearranging:
$$ E[T_n^2] = 2E[T_n] - 1 + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n-1}^2] + \frac{1}{2}E[T_{n+1}^2] $$

This is also a second-order linear difference equation but of a higher order. I tried to write a general form for the solution:

$$ E[T_n^2] = an^4 + bn^3 + cn^2 + dn + e $$
Where $a, b, c, d, e$ are constants we need to determine.
I tried to identify what values these constants need to be:
$ a = \frac{1}{3} , b = 0 , c = 1 ,d = 0 , e = -1 $
Therefore, the solution for $E[T_n^2]$ is:
$$ E[T_n^2] = \frac{1}{3}n^4 + n^2 - 1 $$
Now we can calculate the variance:
$$ \begin{align*}
\text{Var}(T_n) &= E[T_n^2] - (E[T_n])^2 \\
&= (\frac{1}{3}n^4 + n^2 - 1) - (n^2)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{3}n^4 + n^2 - 1 - n^4 \\
&= -\frac{2}{3}n^4 + n^2 - 1
\end{align*} $$
$$ \text{Var}(T_n) = \frac{2}{3}n^4 - n^2 + 1 $$

Did I do ok here?

I presume you mean a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_+$, not the standard one on $\mathbb{Z}$. Also, when you write the equation for $\mathbb{E} T_n$ you implicitly assume that $p=1/2$, not any $p\in(0,1)$.

Suppose $X_n$ is a r.w. on $\mathbb{Z}_+$ with the reflecting barrier such that
$$
X_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
X_n+1, &\text{with probability }p;\\
X_n-1, &\text{with probability }q=1-p
\end{cases}
$$
whenever $X_n\ge 1$, and $X_{n+1}=1$ when $X_n=0$.
Assume $X_0=0$ and let $$T_n=\inf\{n\ge 0:\ X_k=n\}.$$
Let $\mu_n=\mathbb{E} T_n$.
For $p=1/2$ there is the following neat solution: instead of reflecting at $0$, we can imagine that the r.w. is actually on the whole $\mathbb{Z}$ with the same $1/2$ probability of going to $-1$ or $+1$ once it's at $0$. $\mu_n$ will be then the expected time to hit either $-n$ or $n$.
Let
$$
a_k=\mathbb{E}(T_n\mid X_0=k)
$$
Then indeed the equation of $a_k$ is
\begin{align}
(*)\qquad a_k=1+\frac12a_{k-1}+\frac12a_{k+1}
\end{align}
for $-n<k<n$ and $a_{-n}=a_n=0$. It's easy to check that the answer is
$$
a_k=n^2-k^2.
$$
If $p\ne 1/2$, one cannot use this trick. Let $a_k$ be exactly as above, but the equation (*) is replaced by
\begin{align}
(**)\qquad a_k=1+q a_{k-1}+p a_{k+1}\quad\text{for $1\le k\le n-1$.}
\end{align}
We have $a_n=0$ as before, with an extra condition
$$
a_0=a_1+1.
$$
If $b_k=a_{k-1}-a_k$, $k=1,2,\dots,n$, then (**) becomes
$$
p b_{k+1}=q b_k+1
$$
and also $b_1=1$. Hence, by induction, for $k\ge 2$,
$$
b_k=\rho^{k-1}+\frac{1+\rho+\rho^2+\dots+\rho^{k-2}}p
=\rho^{k-1}+\frac{1-\rho^{k-1}}{p-q}
=\frac{1-2q\rho^{k-1}}{p-q}
$$
where $\rho=q/p$, and thus
\begin{align}
a_k&=a_0-b_1-b_2-\dots-b_k=a_0-\frac{k}{p-q}+\frac{2q}{p-q}(1+\rho+\dots+\rho^{k-1})
\\ &=a_0-\frac{k}{p-q}+\frac{2q}{p-q}\frac{1-\rho^k}{1-\rho}
=a_0-\frac{k}{p-q}+\frac{2\rho(1-\rho^k)}{(1-\rho)^2}.
\end{align}
Since $a_n=0$, we have
$$
a_0=\frac{n}{p-q}-\frac{2\rho(1-\rho^n)}{(1-\rho)^2}
$$
and
$$
\mu_n=a_0=\frac{n}{p-q}-\frac{2pq(1-(q/p)^n)}{(p-q)^2}
=\frac{n}{2p-1}-\frac{2p(1-p)(p^n-(1-p)^n)}{(2p-1)^2 p^n}.
$$

thank you so much! Was my approach close?

Can you please show me to do calculate the variance?

thank you so much van der Wolf!

@ Van der wolf: hello! can you please show me how to calculate the variance based on this?

@heartofdarkness, your approach was close in the $p=1/2$ case.

Variance is much harder...

I think you should consult with
William Feller
An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications, Volume I.
I'll get the main one from there
Let $ p_{n}(j)$ be the probability that the first visit to point $j\geqslant 1$ takes place on the nth trial. The the generating function of $ p_{n}(j)$:
$$P_{j}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{n}(j)s^n=\left ( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pqs^2}}{2qs} \right )^j$$
In principle, the entire solution of the problem is compressed into this expression.
From this we get expected time by differentiating with respect to $s$ and then set $s=1$:
$$E(n)=\frac{\mathrm{d} P_{j}(1)}{\mathrm{d} s}=\frac{j}{\sqrt{1-4pq}}\left ( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pq}}{2q} \right )^j$$
Variance:
$$\text{Var}(n)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 P_{j}{(1)}}{\mathrm{d} s^2}+E(n)-E^2(n)$$
The expression for variance is too unwieldy to write out here.
Note that in case of $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $E(n)=\infty$

I am not sure the pgf is relevant for this problem. In any case, the expectation is finite.

This part if for the variance, in the simplest case when $p=1/2$. (General case is quite hard!)
Suppose $X_n$ is a r.w. on $\mathbb{Z}_+$ with the reflecting barrier such that
$$
X_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
X_n+1, &\text{with probability }1/2;\\
X_n-1, &\text{with probability }1/2
\end{cases}
$$
whenever $X_n\ge 1$, and $X_{n+1}=1$ when $X_n=0$.
Assume $X_0=0$ and let $$T_n=\inf\{n\ge 0:\ X_k=n\}.$$
Again, instead of reflecting at $0$, we can imagine that the r.w. is actually on the whole $\mathbb{Z}$ with the same $1/2$ probability of going to $-1$ or $+1$ once it's at $0$.
Let
$$
z_k=\mathbb{E}(T_n^2\mid X_0=k)
$$
Since we can condition on the first step again,
$$
\mathbb{E}(T_n^2\mid X_0=k)
=\frac12\mathbb{E}((T_n+1)^2\mid X_0=k+1)
+\frac12\mathbb{E}((T_n+1)^2\mid X_0=k-1)
$$
Using the fact that $a_k=\mathbb{E}(T_n\mid X_0=k)=n^2-k^2$ as derived before, the equation for $z_k$ is
\begin{align}
(**)\qquad z_k&=1+\frac12z_{k-1}+\frac12z_{k+1}+a_{k-1}+a_{k+1}+1\\
&=\frac12z_{k-1}+\frac12z_{k+1}+2n^2-2k^2-1
\end{align}
for $-n<k<n$ and $z_{-n}=z_n=0$.
Again, denote $w_k=z_k-z_{k-1}$, then (**) becomes
$$
w_{k+1}=w_k+4k^2+2-4n^2,
$$
a general solution to which is
$$
w_k=C+\frac{2(k - 1)k(2k - 1)}3 + (k + 1)(2 - 4n^2)
$$
Since $z_{-n}=0$, for $m=-n+1,-n+2,\dots,n$
\begin{align}
z_m&=w_{-n+1}+w_{-n+2}+\dots+w_m
\\
&=\frac{(m^{3}-nm^{2}-5 n^{2} m +5 n^{3}-18 n^{2}+2 m -2 n +9) (m+n)}{3}+C(m+n).
\end{align}
Using the fact that $z_n=0$, we get that
$$
C=6n^2-3
$$
and thus
$$
z_m=\frac{(n^2-m^2)(5n^2-m^2-2)}3
$$
and since $a_0=\mathbb{E}(T_n\mid X_0=0)=n^2$,
$$
\mathrm{Var}(T_n\mid X_0=k)=z_0-a_0^2=\frac{2n^2(n^2-1)}3.
$$
Note that the variance is zerp when $n=0$ and $n=1$ (in the latter case $T_n\equiv 1$).
