show that $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n} - \tau_n\mathbb{E}\xi_1]^2 = Var(\xi_1) \cdot \mathbb{E}\tau_n$
Probability space $ (\Omega, A, \mathbb{P}),\; \Omega = \{\omega: \omega = (x_1, \dots, x_n), x_i = \pm 1\},\; |\Omega| < \infty  $
$$ 
S_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \xi_i$$
$\mathbb{P}\{\xi_i = 1\} = p,\; \mathbb{P}\{\xi_i = -1\} = q,\; p \neq q, \; p + q = 1$. $\xi_i $ - independent and identically distributed random variables. $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, i \leq n$ 

Then $\mathbb{E}(\xi_i) = p - q,\; \mathbb{E}(S_n) = n(p-q),\; Var(\xi_i) = 1 - (p - q)^2 $. 

$$ \tau_k = \min\{ 0 \leq l \leq k: S_l = A \;or\; B\}, A\leq 0 \leq B $$
$\tau_k = k, \; if A < S_l < B \;\; \forall l  $
$$ S_{\tau_n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} S_k I_{\{\tau_n = k\}} $$ 
Show that
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n} - \tau_n\mathbb{E}\xi_1]^2 = Var\xi_1\mathbb{E}\tau_n = \mathbb{E}\tau_n - (\mathbb{E}\xi_1)^2E\tau_n $$
My attempt:
$$ \mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n} - \tau_n\mathbb{E}\xi_1]^2 = \mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n}^2]^{(1)} + (-2)\mathbb{E}\xi_1\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n}\tau_n]^{(2)} + \mathbb{E}[(\tau_n \mathbb{E}\xi_1)^2]^{(3)} $$
$$ (1) = \mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n}^2] = \mathbb{E}S_n^2 - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb{E}(S_n - S_k)^2 I_{\tau_n = k} = \mathbb{E}[\tau_n] + (\mathbb{E}\xi_1)^2\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k-1) \mathbb{P}\{\tau_n = k\} $$
$$ (3) = \mathbb{E}[(\tau_n \mathbb{E}\xi_1)^2] = (\mathbb{E}\xi_1)^2 \sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2 \mathbb{P}\{\tau_n = k\}  $$
Now it remains to show that
$$ (2) = \mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n}\tau_n] = (\mathbb{E}\xi_1) \sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2 \mathbb{P}\{\tau_n = k\} $$
How to do it?

The second reply might be relevant for your problem:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4979484/on-average-how-long-does-it-take-for-a-random-walk-to-go-somewhere-for-the-firs/4983548#4983548

Hint: To prove $$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau_n} - \tau_n\mathbb{E}\xi_1]^2 = Var(\xi_1)\mathbb{E}\tau_n$$Consider the process $M_k=S_k-k\mathbb{E}\xi_1$, which is a martingale due to the independence and identical distribution of the $\xi_i$ and because $\mathbb{E}[\xi_i-\mathbb{E}\xi_i]=0$. Utilize the property that the expected squared value of a martingale at a stopping time equals the expected total variance up to that time:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[M^2_{\tau_n}\right]=\text{Var}(\xi_1)\mathbb{E}\left[\tau_n\right]$$

Since $M_{\tau_n}=S_{\tau_n}-\tau_n\mathbb{E}\xi_1$ this gives you desired result with no need to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[S_{\tau_n}\tau_n\right]$ explicitly. Feel free to reach out for any queries, I will be back on in the morning.

@keixx Thx for your reply. I came across this statement before the concept of martingales was introduced. I can't prove it in that terminology yet.

I see. I'll think of something without martingales and get back to you, I'm unsure as of now.
